# Stay in Current Activity Instead of Navigating to Back after Send email in android

Tags: android-intent

In my application i am sending email to recipient ,but when  send email current activity is closed and it goes to back activity.But i do not want like that,i want to stay in current activity instead of navigating to back. i used  intent.putExtra(“exit_on_send”,true); and     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)  but it is not work for me .Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

With the very limited data you have given it looks like you are finishing the activity explicitly. Otherwise there is no way why your activity should navigate to the previous one. If you could provide your code snippet it would help to answer better